# How to resolve ERROR: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator in GitLab Integration

Tags: .net, gitlab, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I am configuring a GitLab ci pipeline for a .NET project. I am trying to run the code analysis using the sonar cloud. When I run the analysis I’m stuck at the error saying

`ERROR: You’re not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.` ,

Seems like the analysis report is generated and when it’s trying to upload the analysis report to sonar cloud the execution is getting failed with the error.
Please suggest how to overcome this error and run the analysis successfully.

Commands used in the PowerShell script to run the analysis :

```
echo "sonarqube installation"
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.2.0

dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"proj1" /d:sonar.login="auth-token" /d:sonar.host.url="https://sonarqube-server.com" /d:project.settings="C:\builds\proj1\sonar-project.properties"

# dotnet build command

dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="auth-token"
echo "sonar scanning completed"
```

Here is my sonar-project.properties. I have removed the values for now.

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=proj1
sonar.projectName=proj1
sonar.projectVersion=1.6
sonar.organization=proj1
sonar.sources='sources list'
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=
sonar.javascript.jstest.reportsPath=

#ignore rules
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=

# function complexity
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=

# unused variable
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey=

# function with too many line
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e3.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e3.resourceKey=

# trailing comma
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e4.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e4.resourceKey=

# === and  !==
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e5.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e5.resourceKey=

# Commented Code
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e6.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e6.resourceKey=

# Nested If Depth
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e7.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e7.resourceKey=

sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e8.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e8.resourceKey=

# Trailing Whitespace
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e9.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e9.resourceKey=

# Literal boolean values
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e10.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e10.resourceKey=

# Variables and functions redeclared
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e11.resourceKey=

# Unused function argument
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e12.ruleKey=
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e12.resourceKey=
```

I’ve tried giving all the permissions to run the analysis in sonar cloud.

Comment: I would say that your sonar.login misses 'execute analysis' permission for the project. Check your project permissions.

Comment: @raspy added all the required permissions. The issue is still happening. Can you verify the dotnet command? Maybe the project properties do not read properly.

Comment: Make sure your sonar.organization and sonar.projectKey are correct. You can also add sonar.verbose=true for more debugging information, including actual URLs that are called and their responses. Maybe it will tell you something more.

Comment: @raspy I have checked them. I think the project settings file doesn`t read properly. Scanner considers all the sources instead of the mentioned sources in the settings file.

Comment: `sonar.sources` value is incorrect. If say your source files are present in directory `source`, then you need to provide the value of `sonar.sources= **/source/**`

Comment: @SouravAtta can I use sonar-project.properties file with .Net global tools? Is there any way to use these properties with sonar scan?

Comment: You can modify the **sonar-project.properties** file with the value of sonar.sources. I hope you can modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, not authorized error got solved after generating new token in SONAR (Sonarcloud->Account->Myaccount->Security->Enter token name->Generate->Copy the token) and configure the generated token in bibucket with environment variable named SONAR_TOKEN for the bitbucket repository. Delete any old SONAR_TOKEN configured in bitbucket. Previous token configured was revoked by someone and it resulted in not authorized error.

See if same works in Gitlab integration